# How can I save data to two tables using a single form?

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

How can I save data to two tables using a single form?

This is my likes model:

```
class Like extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','post_id','value',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');


        //$this->belongsTo(User::class);
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        //   return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','user_id');

    }
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');


        //$this->belongsTo(User::class);
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        //   return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','user_id');

    }
```

Post.php

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','content', 'live','post_on','likes'
    ];
    protected $dates = ['post_on'];

    public function SetLiveAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['live'] = (boolean)($value);

    }


    public function getshortContAttribute(){
        return substr($this->content, 0, random_int(60,150)). '...';
    }

    public function SetPostOnAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['post_on'] = Carbon::parse($value);
    }


    public function user()
    {
        //$this->belongsTo(User::class);
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
     //   return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','user_id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');


    }
    public function comment(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
    public function like()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');


        //$this->belongsTo(User::class);
        //return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
        //   return $this->belongsTo('App\User','id','user_id');

    }

}
```

My form uses `method="PUT"`.

Comment: I've cleaned up your formatting, but I don't fully understand your question. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: its done . thank u

Comment: Can you add an example of what you tried so far?